# Access 2007 unwanted rounding off numbers

Tags: ms-access, rounding

I have an access 2007 table with a number field. Properties are Long Integer/general number/2 decimal places. My problem is that when I enter a decimal value it is being rounded off.  I have tried other field sizes and other formats but I cannot get the decimal value to show.

Answer (score 1):

A "Long Integer" cannot have decimal places....

Use

`NUMBER (FieldSize= DOUBLE)` or  `NUMERIC`

See [Microsoft Access Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or as @ Gord Thompson points out, perhaps the `Currency` datatype is a closer match to your needs?

Comment: ...or perhaps `Currency`.

Comment: Good point. I guess I missed the fact that 2 decimal places were important!